# How to add JS to Head tag in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, ab-testing

I need to add a JS script (for A/B Testing) that needs to be executed in the Head tag. How can I ensure that in Odoo that JS I add is added in Head tag and not body or later?

Comment: Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

JS file must be under `yourmodule/static/` folder to be downloadable.

Then, you must link it in an assets view. Imagine this `yourmodule/templates/assets.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>

<template id="assets_common" inherit_id="web.assets_common">
    <xpath expr=".">
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="/yourmodule/static/src/js/abtesting.js"/>
    </xpath>
</template>

</data>
```

By overriding `web.assets_common` view, your code will be available both in the backend and in the frontend. In case you only need one of those, you should override a different view, but given you didn't specify in your question, this is what you get.

Also, remember to add that xml template to your addon's manifest!